# Dimension of the stalk of parallel sections and curvature rank

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle of rank $n$ endowed with a connection $\nabla$. We can define the sheaf of parallel sections by setting $\Gamma_0(U)=\{s\in\Gamma(U):\nabla s=0\}$. Let $\Gamma_0(p)$ be the stalk of this sheaf at a point $p\in M$.

If $\dim\Gamma_0(p)=n$, we can choose a local basis consisting of parallel sections $s_1,\dots, s_n$, and we can show that the curvature $F^\nabla(p)=0$.

In general, is there a numerical relation between $\dim\Gamma_0(p)$ and $\mathrm{rank}F^\nabla(p)$?

Comment: In English, we talk about a sheaf of germs of .... I don’t know what a germ of a sheaf means.

Comment: It's just the germ at the point $p$, of the sheaf.

Comment: In this situation, I may say it's the inductive limit $\lim \Gamma_0(U)$ over all open subsets $U$ containing $p$.

Comment: That is the stalk of the sheaf at $p$, is it not?

Comment: Thank you. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parallel section of $E$ is completely determined by its value at $p \in M$. So you can identify the stalk of this sheaf at $p \in M$ with a linear subspace $W \le T_p M$.

The value of the curvature tensor at a point $p \in M$ can be thought of as an element of $\wedge^2 T^*_p M \otimes T^*_p M \otimes T_p M$. We define the rank of a tensor to be the minimal number of simple tensors needed to express it.

You can check this fact yourself by choosing a basis, but one can show that if you have a tensor $T$ which lives in a vector space $V$ which is made up of some tensor products, then for each linearly independent simple tensor (say $u \in V^*$) such that $ \langle T, u \rangle = 0$, you can bound the rank of $T$ by one.

That said, lets get back to the problem. The usual formulas for dimensions of our spaces tell us that the dimension of $ \wedge^2 T^*_p M \otimes T^*_p M \otimes T_p M$ is $n^3 (n-1)/2$. So that is the maximum possible rank.

Now, if you have $w_1 , \ldots , w_k \in W$ which are linearly independent. Then you know that for $i=1,\ldots k$, we have that:
$$ \forall v_1 , v_2 \in T_p M , \ \eta \in T^* M \qquad \langle F^\nabla (p) , v_1 \wedge v_2 \otimes w_i \otimes \eta \rangle = 0 $$

Since you have $n^2(n-1)/2$-dimensions of choices for $v_1, v_2$ and $\eta$, it follows that the rank of $R^\nabla$ is bounded by $(n-k)n^2 (n-1)/2$. Notice that if $k = n$ then the rank is zero so this agrees with your example case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose the relation you've got is that $\mathrm{rank}R^\nabla(p)\leq\frac{n^2(n-1)(n-\dim\Gamma_0(p))}{2}$? Can you generalize this to the case $E\rightarrow M$ (not necessarily $TM\rightarrow M$)?

Comment: If $E$ has rank $k$ and $dim(\Gamma_0(p)) = m$ then the bound is $ kn (n-1) (k-m)/2$. The argument is the same you just replace some of the numbers when calculating the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. Do we know if this bound is sharp? (i.e. do we have examples when the equality is obtained?)

Comment: I'm confident that it's not sharp but I don't have an example for you.

Comment: You mean that the equality is obtained?

Comment: My guess is that equality is obtained in low dimensions (maybe n=2) but in higher dimensions I doubt it. There are other equations that constrain what possible values curvature takes that can probably be used to reduce the estimation of rank, but I don't really know beyond that.